# pytest mock a function call in __init__ of a class

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

I have a class like this,

```
from external_package.module.sub_module import fun

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = fun()
        
    def printer(self):
        print(f"X : {self.x}, y : {self.y}, z: {self.z}")
```

I want to write a unit test for this class and mock the function call that is happening in the **init** method.

I have tried patching like this,

```
from external_package.module import sub_module
    
def test_my_class(mocker):

    mocker.patch.object(sub_module, 'fun', return_value="this is mocked")
    obj = MyClass(10, 20)
    
    assert obj.z == "this is mocked"
```

But I can see that the call is not patched and a function call happens in the **init** method.

How can I patch the call with pytest-mock or any other mocking packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by slightly changing the import statement in the source code,

```
from external_package.module import sub_module 

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.z = sub_module.fun()
        
    def printer(self):
        print(f"X : {self.x}, y : {self.y}, z: {self.z}")
```

Note that I'm importing submodule and calling method from the imported sub_module.

Now, in the test I used the `pytest-mock` fixture like this,

```
import external_package
    
def test_my_class(mocker):

    method = mocker.patch("external_package.module.sub_module.fun")
    method.return_value = "this is mocked"

    obj = MyClass(10, 20)
    
    assert obj.z == "this is mocked"
```

I'm not sure why this worked and not the earlier approach. Hope someone can clear that.

Comment: In your second implementation you were very specific of what function should be mocked, you defined that the function `fun` from `sub_module` when executed inside `external_package` is mocked and must return "this is mocked". In you first implementation you mocked `sub_module` but didn't specify where it should be mocked.

Answer (score 2):

You should mock your function with the path where it's been used and not it's original path or location. In the example bellows it's defined that the fun method  in the object MyClass will be mocked and the returned value will be "this is mocked".

```
from external_package.module import sub_module
from my_class import MyClass

def test_my_class(mocker):

    mocker.patch.object(MyClass.submodule, 'fun', return_value="this is mocked")
    obj = MyClass(10, 20)
    
    assert obj.z == "this is mocked"
```

Check this [link](https://medium.com/@yeraydiazdiaz/what-the-mock-cheatsheet-mocking-in-python-6a71db997832) for some good examples of how to mock objects in Python.

Comment: This is running in to error : MyClass has no attribute named fun.

Comment: I forgot to add sub_module after MyClass but already update it. sorry about the mistake.